# Is it possible to use common or standard ARM template to create different type of logquery and metric alerts?

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-rm-template

Looking for a solution to get a common deployment template which I can reuse independently with different type of alerts.  Azure is providing different kind alerts like log query based alerts and metric based alerts. Also within them we have different kind of options, for example, inside logsearch type we have "metrimeasure" and "numberofresults" type alerts, and within them we have different options for timeAggregation and dimension values. So I was looking for a common template where I can reuse it with different kind of alerts with its own specific threshold and related configuration, basically the template should be capable to create the alerts according to the input given (basically, how it should segregate itself in accordance with the parameter values input).

Right now, I am using Azure devops pipeline with runtime parameter values  to replace the values of a parameter.json first and  which will be using by a common template for the type of "Count" type in logquery kind of alert. But If I use the type as other "Total" or kind as "metricmeasurement", then the required options in the ARM template will be entirely different and getting failed with irrelevant data input for the json.

So only option which i am seeing is having different template.json file and parameter values for each kind of these alerts and setup the condition inside each task of my pipeline to replace the parameter.json accordingly and use the deployment template file.

Is there any solution for the above concern where how we can use a common template?

If no solution, Whether its possible to have a common parameter file, where can have all set of the parameters values( will be replacing the values "#{}#", with replace token and use with different kind based common templates. I meant, the parameter files values will not be relevant or not be replaced for other components which are not relevant to for particular alert which is going to create (As the given values are only for the specific alert type and still the parameters.json have values to replace with "#{}#", will this pass the deployment or throw error?

Comment: It's a **parameter**  - not a "paramater" .....

Comment: Have you looked into using Bicep? You may find the [Bicep Modules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/modules) are a good way of making and using templates.

Comment: is there any samples where i can reuse this in accordacne with my scenario..